# How to write 'In' queries in WCF Data Services?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

How to write 'In' queries in <strike>Ado.Net</strike> WCF Data Services? I have tried the following code.

```
IList<int> orderIds = new List<int> { 59810, 59811, 59812, 59813, 59814 };
var lstorders = _context.Orders
                        .Where(o => orderIds.Contains(o.customerId))
                        .ToList<Orders>();
```

But the above code is not working. I am getting following error.

> Test 'MyTest' failed: System.NotSupportedException : The
>   expression (([10007].customerId !=
>   null) And
>   value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]).Contains([10007].customerId.Value))
>   is not supported.
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.ExpressionToString(DataServiceContext
>   context, Expression e)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryOptionExpression(FilterQueryOptionExpression
>   fqoe)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryOptions(ResourceExpression
>   re)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitResourceSetExpression(ResourceSetExpression
>   rse)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.Translate(DataServiceContext
>   context, Boolean addTrailingParens,
>   Expression e, Uri& uri, Version&
>   version)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Translate(Expression
>   e)
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
>       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
>       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)

Comment: "ADO.NET Data Services" (f.k.a. "Astoria) have been renamed **WCF Data Services** well over a year ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help.

[Select entities where ID in int array - WCF Data Services, LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521346/select-entities-where-id-in-int-array-wcf-data-services-linq)

Answer (score 1):

WCF Data Service 'WHERE IN', 'WHERE NOT IN' extension method [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Data-Service-5de13c3d)