# Change supported OData Protocol version when using MVC ODataController

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata

I am using VS2013 with MVC and exposing a simple ODataController.

In fact, I basically followed the tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx

I am trying to consume the service on android with odata4j and currently running into an issue that the odata metadata reports that it only supports 3.0 version of the protocol (min + max) as seen here: -

```
 <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
```

I tried changing this in the EdmModel in WebApiConfig.cs file.

```
 ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 builder.DataServiceVersion = new Version(2, 0);
 builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
```

This fixes the $metadata response but does not go deep enough as the response headers report the following (Note DataServiceVersion is still 3.0).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 06:20:40 GMT
Content-Length: 1457
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here or is there a proper approach to adjusting the support OData protocol versions for the service?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to add a DataServiceVersion header in the request:

```
GET /odata/Customers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:42980
Connection: keep-alive
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)...
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2013 05:51:51 GMT
Content-Length: 24
```

Comment: That is fine, but how would I go about doing that? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Try the solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842410/dataserviceversion-conflict-the-dataserviceversion-1-0-is-too-low-for-the-req)

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of a better answer:

You may be able to override the header value by manipulating the [request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.request.aspx)'s [headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers.aspx) within your controller, depending on how the header is set by the OData extension code. **This is not the correct solution**, merely a work-around. Don't accept it even if it works.

PS: If you don't receive a proper answer here, you might want to either ask for information [directly from the developers](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/5322/asp-net-web-api), or simply read the [code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http.OData/), in order to determine how that header is set and whether you or they are doing something wrong (because in my opinion it's not obvious that you are).

Answer (score 0):

OData v4 uses new header names to communicate the requested OData version.

From [What’s New in OData Version 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.0/cn01/new-in-odata-v4.0-cn01.html#_Toc366145441):

> *OData-Version* replaced the former *DataServiceVersion*,
>   *OData-MaxVersion* replaced *MaxDataServiceVersion*, ...

And there are many other changes that were introduced with v4.

So, to speak OData v4 it is not enough to modify the version numbers in the headers.
Instead you have to use other Nuget packages:

**For OData v1 to v3:**
Use the OData Nuget Package **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData** which comes in version 5.x.

**For OData v4:**
Use the latest OData Nuget Package **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** with version number 7.x or higher.