# How to merge DataServiceQuery expression with AddQueryOption

Tags: linq, odata, wcf-data-services

OData linq doesn't support contains or any kind of "in" check. To solve this problem guys proposed following solution:

[OData "where ID in list" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745231/odata-where-id-in-list-query)

The problem is that I want to mix this solution with regular Where clause. If I just add AddQueryOption I will clean all previous filters added by Where. I have tried to extract initial $filter generated by Where and append to it "in" clause and then call AddQueryOption - without any success. As far as I see most of the classes that translate expression are internal. So I could not find any way to inject custom code. Any ideas how to do this?
Generally I want something like this:

```
 provider.Collection.Where(data => data.Name ="aaa" and categories.Contains(data.CategoryId))
```

Code that unfortunatelly not solve this:

```
   private DataServiceQuery<TElement> AddContains(DataServiceQuery<TElement> query, string [] categories)
   {
    var filterParams = categories.Select(id => string.Format("(CategoryId eq '{0}')", id));
    var filter = string.Join(" or ", filterParams);
    //filter = originalFilter + " and " + string.Join(" or ", filterParams); 
    // also doesn't work
    return query.AddQueryOption("$filter", filter);
  }
   var query = provider.Collection.Where(data => data.Name ="aaa") as DataServiceQuery<TElement>;
   var results = AddContains(query, new string[] {"1","2"}).Execute().ToList();
```