# Does odata support to get entities by multiple ids?

Tags: odata

Generally I want some equivalent of:

```
select * from my_entity where id IN (1,2,3)
```

In odata it should be like that:

```
GET http://my-host.com/Api/V4/MyEntity(1,2)
```

But for API which I try to use the upper url does not work :( So does `odata` API supports get entities by multiple ids? If yes - what url pattern to use?

Comment: Looks like this is already answered here: [OData "where ID in list" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745231/odata-where-id-in-list-query)

Comment: alternatively, if your odata service supports $batch requests, you can send multiple GETs in one request.