# OData v4 $filter IN Operator supported by Kendo UI grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

Does anyone know if Kendo UI grid fully supports OData v4 operators, such as the IN operator? Or would I have to have multiple OR statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it doesn't really matter if Kendo supports it, if your server supports `in` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745231/odata-where-id-in-list-query), ODATA 4.0.1 does), you can set the extra clause in the `transport\read\data` property of the JSON object.

```
var dataSource = {
        type: "odata-v4",
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/odata/MyEndpoint",
                data: {
                    '$filter': 'Name in ('Milk', 'Cheese')'
                    // @Dean Line above is what I meant                                   
                },
                cache: false
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id"
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "id",
            dir: "desc"
        },
        pageSize: 20
    };
```

Comment: How do I know if my server supports it? That is probably a silly question. I know my DB server supports an `IN` operator. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You have to see which version of ODATA you have exposed in your webapi - note that ODATA != SQL (DB). There are two completely different domains.

Comment: Oh gottcha! I haven't implemented OData in my project yet, so I guess I will use the latest OData library from Microsoft. Currently, I am using a parser called StringToExpression to create OData "like" queries.