# Looping through Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I have a linq query that pulls data from an odata service like so:

```
var Query = from t in results.People
   where t.Invalid == false && t.Id == 148
   select new
   {
    t.Name,
    t.Location
   }
```

I also have a string array of Ids {148,149,150...} and I would like to replace the `t.Id == 148` expression above with each of those Ids from the array.

I am not sure how the syntax for that goes, if it is even possible without a for loop.
Can someone please let me know if it is possible?

Comment: Is your list large?  You can see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521346/select-entities-where-id-in-int-array-wcf-data-services-linq

Comment: It is not large, about 30 entries or so.

Comment: Then go to the answer I linked above and do the $filter answer with concatenation to send it to the odata server.

Answer (score 3):

For OData you can try:

```
var Query = from t in results.People
            from r in ids
            where t.Invalid == false && t.Id = r
            select new
            {
                t.Name,
                t.Location
            };
```

This will return you all rows with matching ids from your array `ids`

For LINQ to objects or LINQ to SQL/Entity framework generally the query is:

```
var Query = from t in results.People
   where t.Invalid == false && ids.Contains(t.Id)
   select new
   {
    t.Name,
    t.Location
   };
```

Comment: I don't believe OData supports contains.

Comment: Correct. I get `cannot convert from 'long[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<long?>`. But is there a way to create a dynamic string which would look like this `t.Id == 148 || t.Id == 149` etc? For all values in the array?

Comment: Hmm now I get `The method 'Select' is not supported.` when trying to iterate through the Query var like so `foreach (var detail in Query) {  name = detail.Name;
 location = detail.Location; }`

Comment: @sd_dracula, Can you try couple of things. First create a temporary class and then project to its properties like `select new MyClass { Name = t.Name, Location = t.Location}` instead of anonymous type. I believe this should work, you can also try explicitly specifying field names with anonymous types like `select new { Name= t.Name, Location = t.Location}`

Comment: I am getting a similar error via the class also: `{Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported.}`

Comment: @sd_dracula, Ok one more try, can you just ditch the anonymous type and just do `select t`. Later you can do the projection in linq to objects.

Answer (score 0):

If OData doesn't support contains, what about Any?

```
from t in results.People
where t.Invalid == false && ids.Any(id => id == t.Id)
select new
{
    t.Name,
    t.Location
};
```